# Unit test exception when calling API service using IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: api, .net-core, xunit, httpcontext

I have a service class in my .net-core web api that is working fine.  The constructor for this class takes the IHttpContextAccessor interface as an argument.  This allows me to get at some information in the request header.  However, when I call this service in an unit test (xUnit) an exception is thrown.  This happens at the line where it tries to assign the request header value to the LIS_USER variable.

The exception error is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.  In my unit test, I added some values to the request header using HttpRequestMessage but that didn't help.  It seems like IHttpContextAccessor is not valid or has not been instantiated.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks, Tom

```
namespace LIS_API.Services
{
    public class PartialService : ServiceBase, IPartialService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpctx;

        private string LIS_USER = "";

        public PartialService(DbDataContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpctx)
            : base(context)
        {
            _httpctx = httpctx;
            LIS_USER = _httpctx.HttpContext.Request.Headers["LIS_UID"];
        }

        //service logic....

    }       
}
```

Comment: Show the test. Are you passing in a value for the accessor?

Comment: I am.  I was able to resolve by checking to see if that value was null.  If so, I just assigned some dummy test values for the request header fields.